# Open api generated client fails when calling PATCH endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator to generate client and server code. I have generated a patch endpoint with the following logic:

```
/renting-interested-persons/v1/interested-persons:
      patch:
  description: Change status on interested persons
  operationId: changeStatusOnPersons
  tags:
    - renting
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ChangeStatusDTO'
  responses:
    204:
      description: Status of interested persons is changed
```

The endpoint is generated and tested and it's working. Now I am trying to call this endpoint from another microservice using the client generated code and for every other endpoint is ok except for this which is a PATCH.

This is the way that I am creating a client:

```
private ApiClient getMyApiClient() {
    ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient();
    apiClient.setDebugging(true);
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(addToken)) {
        final String token = tokenProvider.getTokenFromAzure();
        apiClient.setBearerToken(token);
    }
    apiClient.setBasePath(MyBaseUrl);
    return apiClient;
}
```

And after that just getting this client and calling the endpoint:

```
getInterestedPersonApi().changeStatusOnPersons(changeStatusDTO);
```

The exception that I am getting is:

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException' exception.
I/O error on PATCH request for "http://localhost:8083/my-endpoint": Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the ApiClient did the trick:

```
private ApiClient getMyApiClient() {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(getRestTemplate());
    apiClient.setDebugging(true);
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(addToken)) {
        final String token = tokenProvider.getTokenFromAzure();
        apiClient.setBearerToken(token);
    }
    apiClient.setBasePath(myBaseUrl);
    return apiClient;
}

private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```